# numeric validation in struts2

Tags: validation, struts2

i want to validate textfield which should allow only number 0-9 in any range
how can i implement this

Answer (score 4):

Struts2 ships with pretty good documentation. Learn how to use it :)

1. Start [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/docs/guides.html).
2. There's chapter [*Validation*](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/docs/validation.html).
3. Check section [*Bundled Validators*](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/docs/validation.html#Validation-BundledValidators).
4. You want to use [*int validation*](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/docs/int-validator.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "in any range". To do numeric validation you can use the int validator:

```
     <validator type="int">
          <param name="fieldName">myfield</param>
          <param name="min">0</param>
          <param name="max">9</param>
          <message>MyField needs to be between ${min} and ${max}</message>
      </validator>
```

I assume you just want integers and not real numbers.

[This](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/validation.html) page describes all the validators that are available.